# Disable Tweak mode / hide screen space transform gizmos?

Tags: 3d-view, transforms, gizmo

I do not want to work in screen space. But every time I try to transform something in Blender I am confronted with the dreaded screen space gizmo. I just want to work in object space or world space. Never, ever screen space. Never, ever "tweak mode". It's super sloppy and difficult to control. How can I make the transform gizmos always operate in the current coordinate system?

After much grief, I was able to figure out how to make the G/R/S hotkeys invoke tripod transform gizmos for Move / Rotate / Scale -- like in every other 3D program. But I cannot get rid of the white circle that transforms in Tweak mode.

Please tell me how I can get rid of the dreaded Tweak mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off the gizmos completely using the Overlays options at the top of the screen. I personally have them off because they don't serve much purpose once you're committed to the use of hotkeys to do all your transforms.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I knew about that, but it's too extreme. I guess there must be hotkeys for axis constraints, too, but in that case there's no visual feedback on the direction of transforms.

Comment: There are indeed hotkeys for axis constraints. Press "g" for grab, and then X, Y, or Z to constrain that axis. Also, you always have a Worldspace axis indicator in the top-right of the 3D View, which helps ensure that you always know which axis constraint to invoke when needed. Plus, when you get a lot of experience navigating the UI, you don't even need to look at the indicator in many cases, since you remember that Z is up, for example. So it seems perfect for me to get rid of the gizmo entirely. I don't know what to tell you if you want to keep the gizmo handles, but get rid of the circle.

Comment: Well, I already remapped the hotkeys for G/R/S to invoke the gizmos rather than the hated Tweak mode. The axis constraint hotkeys only work for that momentary tweak mode. I.e. one must press G and then immediately press X. Then after performing the transform, the tool reverts to whatever the user was previously doing. Ugh, this is just so dysfunctional. I want to choose an axis constraint and have it stick. I don't want to have to keep repeating the G, X hotkey combination a million times over and over and over.

Comment: So, in 3ds Max, I can invoke axis constraints using hotkeys or the transform gizmo. That means I can choose a transform axis, then zoom in super close on something, click and drag a wireframe, and the object only moves in the axis I previously chose. The transform gizmo does not need to be visible. If I want, I can reveal a toolbar that displays the current axis constraint, but it's not required. This workflow is critical for making fine adjustments. Please tell me how I can do this in Blender without having to click G, X every single time I want to move an object in X.

Comment: This is how problematic Blender is. I want to find a hotkey binding. What is the hotkey to constrain to X? Enter the word "axis" in the Name search field of the Keymap. It doesn't show the command. Enter the word "constrain" and again, no result. But if I enter the letter "x" in the Key-Binding field, I get the desired result, which is "Transform Modal Map > X Axis". OK, now I try to search for any part of the name "Transform Modal Map" and again, get no results. So I need to already know the hotkey that I'm looking for in order to find it.

Comment: The only thing I can tell you is that you don't have to push 'x' after pressing 'g'. You can press 'g', then hold middle-mouse button, and then with a mouse gesture in a given direction, constrain to the axis that corresponds to the direction in which your mouse moved. Won't work if you've remapped 'g', of course. I don't know what to tell you. Outside of scripting, there may be no solution. It sounds like you really don't like Blender. Maybe you could use Max?

Comment: Thanks, that is a great tip. I ended up trashing my custom hotkeys and going back to the default ones. I'm not loving Blender so far, but I have to use it for work. I'm sure once I get past the many problems with the UI, things will get better. "A lousy craftsman blames his tools"